# Maven: permission denied to artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

When I'am trying to build project with maven and I'am getting an error: `could not load dependencies from artifactory. permission denied:connect`.

My `.m2/settings.xml` is ok and VPN connection is up (credentials is ok). Also I can open artifactory from browser or can ping from command line. I'am using maven 3.2.5 like all teammates.

But if I build project from eclipse with embedded maven version (3.0.2), the project builds successfully. Also if I'am using maven 3.0.2 locally, there is no problems with connection. The problem just on my pc, the project has no errors.

Comment: Use `-e` in your maven command [eg `mvn install -e`] which will give stacktrace and post the stacktrace in the question

Comment: Change the embedded version in your eclipse cause 3.0.2 has many bugs...change to use 3.2.5 consistently everywhere. Furthermore check if in your settings.xml the id for the repository server are correctly named and given the correct credentials...

Comment: It's funny, but when i change embeded version of maven to 3.2.5, I get the same error like in command line. Settings.xml  and credentials are 100% correct, because on another PC there is no errors with these credentials and settings.xml file.

Comment: Check that you haver the certificate of the repository installed on your machine if you use SSL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows OS, this issue may related to the ipv4/ipv6
Try to add

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

when you are running the maven build command